# Website shows sitecore login page

Tags: redirect, authentication, sitecore

We just went live with a new Website that's using Sitecore. In the last couple of days, we have heard users complain that they are seeing the Sitecore login page on the live website for the links they bookmarked or just randomly. We are using a load balancer with 3 servers behind that load balancer. Also, the authoring server is behind a firewall and the authoring interface is only accessible via VPN.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the `web.config` details of the `<sites>` section?

Comment: It won't let me post here but basically it contains the following sites - shell, login, admin, service, modules_shell, modules_website, website, scheduler, system, publisher.

Comment: You need to post the details. That's default information. Please post the snippet itself.

Comment: It won't let me post the entire thing. Here is the bit for the website site <site name="website" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content/[sitename]" startItem="/Home" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="200MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false"/>

Comment: Are these end users or users who potentially would have logged into Sitecore at some point?

Comment: this was due to a CMS side page being exposed to the world. We have deleted the sitecore login folder from the front end servers.

Comment: I think your solution is more of a removal of a symptom, but yes it will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would it be possible to have a deny permission on sitecore shell directory for your main website? This way users cannot access sitecore from your main website.

You can still have sitecore enabled on your authoring server though.

This issue has happened to me a couple of times, and I figured out that at some point you must have logged in to sitecore from that browser. Can the users try accessing your website from another browser? It should work fine.
I haven't been able to figure out why this happens though, may be because of cookies.

Comment: I just had a similar issue with a site I'm developing. Deleted cookies and loaded the page fine.

Answer (score 5):

Like techphoria414 said, opening the site in a new browser or clearing the cookies solves the problem.
But to add more detail to this, the cookie responsible for this is:

**website#sc_mode** with the value "edit" or "preview".

If the users with the problem have been editing the site or using the page editor mode, this cookie gets created. Even if they log out, sometimes the cookie stays there and when they try to access the live site, Sitecore answers with a 302 (redirect) to the login page because of this cookie.
They can either delete all cookies or simply this one.